# Solr search query using rest API

Tags: rest, solr, solr4

My requirement is to send a search query to the Solr server through a Rest API and retrieve results.

Is there a facility to send search queries using a Rest API?

If the non-rest query is `field1:name1`, what should the body of the JSON would be? (assuming there exist such a facility in Solr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "through a Rest API", all queries are by default submitted through a standard HTTP query interface. Query `/solr/corename/select?q=field1:name1` to retrieve documents matching the query. You can rename `select` if you want it to match a more REST-ish naming scheme, such as /documents.

.. so it kind of depends on what your definition of a "Rest API" is.

There is way of making query requests through a content stream. If you don't want to use regular `GET` arguments (`?q=field:foo&fq=field2:foo2`), you can make a POST request (and for very extensive queries, that might be necessary) instead.

Comment: I wanted to get result by making a POST request. Is there a documentation on the body syntax of POST request?

Comment: It's the same as for GET. There is no difference. A POST request has the same form for the data string as an argument string for a GET query.

Comment: Hi I want to add data to solr core. How can i do that using Rest API. I want to send data from Postman and call Rest API of Solr to add data to Solr core.

Comment: @ashworx Please ask a new question with information about what you've tried and what you expected to happen, don't comment on old answers with questions.

Comment: Can u reply to it    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562873/index-data-into-solr-core-using-postman