# Index Data into Solr Core using Postman

Tags: solr

I have created a Solr core. Now i want to insert data into it using Postman. Can we do that and how can we insert data to solr core using Postman. Is there any REST API in Apache SOLR which can be directly called from Postman and insert data to Solr Core.

This is my JSON data which i want to insert. I am getting this exception

**Exception writing document id 6 to the index; possible analysis error: For input string: \"\"","code":400}}**

```
 [{
      "id":6,
      "AssetId": 123456,
      "Availability": "Up"
   },
   {
         "id":7,
       "AssetId": 223456,
        "Availability": "Up"
    },
   {
         "id":8,
         "AssetId": 987456,
         "Availability": "Up"
    },
   {
          "id":9,
        "AssetId": 122726,
        "Availability": "Up"

     }]
```

I want to insert this data to my SOLR Core names as asset. But I am getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates), you should be able to index that directly:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update' --data-binary '
[
 {
"id" : "978-0641723445",
 "cat" : ["book","hardcover"],
 "name" : "The Lightning Thief",
 "author" : "Rick Riordan",
 "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians", 
 "sequence_i" : 1,
 "genre_s" : "fantasy",
 "inStock" : true,
 "price" : 12.50,
 "pages_i" : 384
  },
  {
  ...
  }
]'
```

If you need to further transform the data, you should look into [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+and+Indexing+Custom+JSON)

Comment: I donot want to use Curl

Comment: Curl is just showing what/how to send in the request.